# Woocommerce How to hide add to cart button behind a password

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Been trying to find some information on how to hide the add to cart button on specific products behind a password (preset by myself) that then allows the add to cart button to return once entered.

I've got limited coding experience but once it's there I can understand the basics of it, but I understand WooCommerce well enough.

Spent a while researching and trying various things, cant seem to find a plugin that does this either. I don't want to hide the product behind a paywall, nor do I want it to not be indexed / searchable

Comment: Welcome. We expect you to provide in your question your own real code attempt, as stack overflow is code oriented and plugin recommendations are off-topic. So you need to better search and/or code this feature yourself, then if you have some issues with your code you can ask a question providing the related code and details. See [Asking section](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking).